# How do i modify this code To copy and add the values and not the formulas?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have this snipped of code, but i ran into a problem with a table that has some formulas in it, and it copies said formulas instead of the values

```
Book.Sheets(Site).Range("BE19:CN57").Copy
        OtherBook.Sheets(site).Range("BE19:CN57").PasteSpecial _
        Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
```

I have tried this alternate way of doing it

```
auxiliaryRangeMonth = Book.Sheets(site).Range("BE19:CN57")
    auxiliaryRangeYear = OtherBook.Sheets(site).Range("BE19:CN57")
    
    auxiliaryRangeYear.Value = auxiliaryRangeYear.Value + auxiliaryRangeMonth.Value
```

Neither of these approaches work properly

I expected one of these ways of doing it to work, but I am drawing a blank

Comment: Specifically what does it do instead of work?  Your second approach will not work: you missed the `Set` when assigning the ranges, but also you can't add two arrays like that using `+`

Comment: Is the source range filtered?

Comment: Try `OtherBook.Sheets(site).Range("BE19:CN57")..PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only paste the values in a range, you can use the Paste parameter for the PasteSpecial method. Use *xlPasteValues* to copy only the values, or *xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats* to copy the number formats as well (if important).

```
Book.Sheets(Site).Range("BE19:CN57").Copy
OtherBook.Sheets(site).Range("BE19:CN57").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=PasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
```

Comment: I was working on some other stuff after asking this question, sorry for the delay, but this worked like a charm, thank you